# Expectation and variance of bivariate skew normal distribution

Tags: mathematical-statistics, variance, expected-value, computational-statistics, bivariate

I am fitting a bivariate skew normal distribution to a 2D data through the `sn` package in `R`. I get a $2 \times 1$ vector of location and shape parameters $\beta$ and $\alpha$ as well as a $2 \times 2$ scale matrix $\omega$.

In the case of univariate skew normal distribution, I understand the expectation and the variance is given by,

$$
\mu_x = \beta + \omega\delta \sqrt{ \frac{2}{\pi}}
$$ and

$$
\sigma_x^2 = \omega^2\left(1-\frac{2\delta^2}{\pi}\right)
$$

where

$$
\delta = \frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{1+\alpha^2}}
$$

and I can compute these quantities when we fit the data.

However, here we have bivariate distribution - I have vector quantities and I think we will end up with a vector of expectation and variance, one for each dimension. I am not sure how to compute them through the parameters I got through fitting. Specifically, how do I compute $\delta$ and $\delta^2$ as vectors. Please help.

Comment: In multivariate settings, covariances also appear. In two dimensions, this means estimating a 2x2 covariance matrix (with 3 parameters).

Comment: Thanks! How do I compute it then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Azzalini and Della Valle ([Biometrika, 1996](https://academic.oup.com/biomet/article/83/4/715/253295)) have defined a bivariate skew Normal distribution, with density
$$f_2(x,y;\theta)=2\phi_2(x,y;\omega)\Phi(\alpha_x x+\alpha_y y)$$
where $\Phi$ is the standard Normal cdf and $\phi_2(\cdot,\cdot;\omega)$ denotes the density of a bivariate Normal distribution with mean $0_2$ and covariance matrix
$$\Omega=\left(\begin{matrix}1 &\omega\\\omega &1\end{matrix} \right)$$
(The paper relates the $\alpha_i$'s to $\delta_i$'s in $(-1,1)$ that generalise the $\delta$ found in the univariate case.)
It generalises to $\mathbb R^k$ as
$$f_k(z;\theta)=2\phi_k(z;\Omega)\Phi(\alpha^\mathsf{T} z)$$
where $$Z_j=\delta_j|Y_0|+\sqrt{1-\delta_j^2}Y_j,\qquad
(Y_1,\ldots,Y_k)^\mathsf{T}\sim\mathcal N_k(0_k,\Omega),\,Y_0\sim\mathcal N(0,1)$$
Since the density is available in closed form, the parameters can be estimated by regular maximization of the likelihood function. ([An EM algorithm](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s40300-021-00227-4) can also be used in relation with the latent variable associated with the Normal cdf.)

Comment: Thanks! An R code will be terrific for people to implement right away.